# Alternative way to solve large number factorial in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a factorial large number in R, such as `1000!/500!` or  `1/300!`. But I don't want to use any package from R, is there an alternative way to use `lfactorial` and `exp` combined together to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you check out [this](https://lucidmanager.org/euler-problem-20/)?

Comment: I believe you are out of luck. `lfactorial(1000) - lfactorial(500)` is equal to `sum(log(501:1000))`. Then `exp(3300.798)` returns `Inf`.